# string still shows garbled characters after converting encoding from ascii to utf-8

Tags: python, email, encoding

I converted a string

```
body = 'e n=C3=A3o =C3=A9 o =C3=BAnico autor a poder aceit=C3=A1-la'
```

with

```
bodys = bodys.encode('utf-8')
```

but I still see the garbled characters `"=C3=A9"`

this is a string parsed from an email body via `IMapClient` module.
Would you know if there is a way to convert to readable characters?

many thanks!

Comment: Those are all *UTF8* (even *ASCII*) *char*s.

Comment: What where you expecting to convert them into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [`quopri` (quoted printable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) string there.

To get a text string out of that you must:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> s = 'e n=C3=A3o =C3=A9 o =C3=BAnico autor a poder aceit=C3=A1-la'
>>> s_binary = s.encode('UTF-8')
>>> s_binary
b'e n=C3=A3o =C3=A9 o =C3=BAnico autor a poder aceit=C3=A1-la'
>>> s_utf8 = codecs.decode(s_binary, 'quopri')
>>> s_utf8
b'e n\xc3\xa3o \xc3\xa9 o \xc3\xbanico autor a poder aceit\xc3\xa1-la'
>>> s_text = s_utf8.decode('UTF-8')
>>> s_text
'e não é o único autor a poder aceitá-la'
```

Or putting it all together:

```
>>> codecs.decode(s.encode('UTF-8'), 'quopri').decode('UTF-8')
'e não é o único autor a poder aceitá-la'
```